# Focussed database profiling for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

The requirement seems trivial to me, but I am unable to find this in reference documents and CLI help either.

I am currently looking at an output generated out of

`firebase database:profile`

and it provides me a list of sections suc as Uploaded Bytes, Downloaded Bytes, Speed etc

Is there a way to pass some parameter to the CLI like `--bandwidth` to only focus on the Downloaded Bytes section for an example?

Comment: All of the command line flags can be seen using `firebase database:profile --help`.  If you don't see it there, it's not possible.  If you have a feature request for the CLI, file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for pointing to GitHub, have [started a discussion](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/discussions/6762) under the repository to see if this could go through.